# Como faço para mostrar uma notification badge quando recebo uma notificação?

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notificação

Olá, em meu aplicativo tenho uma lista que mostra os usuários que enviaram mensagens. Quero colocar uma notification badge quando o usuário recebe uma notificação. Alguma idéia de como posso conseguir tal função? Segue meu código:

```
class MessagesGet extends StatelessWidget {

  FirebaseUser _currentUser;

  DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

MessagesGet(this._currentUser, this.snapshot);

  Future<FirebaseUser> loadCurrentUser() async {
  if (_currentUser == null)
  _currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
  if (_currentUser != null) {
  if (_currentUser == null) {

    await Firestore.instance.collection('users')
        .document(_currentUser.uid)
        .get();
         print(_currentUser.uid);
     }
   }
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: 

Firestore.instance.collection('chat').document(_currentUser.uid)
.collection('users').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {

        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );


      } else {
        return Scaffold(

          body: ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MessagesScreen(snapshot.data.documents[index], _currentUser);
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    },
   ),
  );
 }
}


class MessagesScreen extends StatelessWidget {

 DocumentSnapshot snapshot;

 FirebaseUser _currentUser;

MessagesScreen(this.snapshot,this._currentUser);


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return
      ListTile(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0),
        leading: CircleAvatar(
          radius: 25.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data["photo"]),
        ),
        title: Text(
          snapshot.data["name"],
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        trailing: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
          child: Badge(),
        ),


        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AdminChat(_currentUser, snapshot)));

        },
      );


 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, o seu exemplo não é testável, o que significa que ninguém aqui vai conseguir rodar seu código e ver o que está ou não funcionando.

Mas levando em conta que você quer apresentar um badge de nova notificação, com um número ou um símbolo acima de um ícone, bastaria utilizar `Stack` em conjunto com `Positioned`:

```dart
Widget _buildNotificationIcon(int total) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.notifications),
        Positioned(
          top: 0.0,
          left: 0.0,
          child: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  '$total',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 10.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              color: Colors.orange,
            ),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 10),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Sobre quando ou não mostrar esse ícone vai depender exclusivamente da sua lógica e de como você gerencia seu estado. Teste esse código na prática [com o dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/7372cba4e88eb136411b3aba789a98c8).

Isso irá produzir essa saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Customize conforme achar necessário. Se a sua pergunta se referia ao recebimento de push notification pelo firebase, não ficou claro o suficiente o problema, aí você terá que seguir a documentação do plugin [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging).

Comment: Julio obrigado pela sua atenção, não coloquei o codigo todo pois ficaria muito grande. No caso descobri um pluggin que ja me da o badge só declarando o child 'Badge", que esta no trailing da minha ListTile. No caso a minha dúvida é como acionar esse badge para aparecer só quando tiver uma nova notificação.

Comment: Então, conforme eu citei na minha resposta também, se você quer tal funcionalidade vai ter que implementar o push notification com o plugin firebase_messaging, a documentação contém um passo a passo. Ou, uma forma incorreta, que seria ficar sempre consultando seu backend para mostrar as notificações disponíveis.